# How to get distinct records from JSON based on specific field

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have JSON records. Where name field has many duplicate records. Based on name I want to get distinct records.
This is my data

```
{
    "name": "ABER",
    "value":72,
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "value":72,
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "value":72,
},
{
    "name": "OCL",
    "value":42,
},
{
    "name": "OCL",
    "value":42,
},
```

This output I am looking for

```
{
    "name": "OCL",
    "value":42,
},
{
    "name": "ABER",
    "value":72,
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "value":72,
},
```

I tried this but it is returning `name` field only not `value` along with

```
var op= Array.from(new Set(obj.map((item: any) => item.name)))
```

How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.reduce to get the required result, like so:

```js
let a = [{
    "name": "ABER",
    "value":72,
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "value":72,
},
{
    "name": "HDCC",
    "value":72,
},
{
    "name": "OCL",
    "value":42,
},
{
    "name": "OCL",
    "value":42,
}]

let result = Object.values(a.reduce((res, el) => { 
    res[el.name] = { ...el, count: res[el.name] ? res[el.name].count + 1: 0};
    return res;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great, glad it was of some help! :-)

Comment: Hi, Just one question is that possible to add/get count field of all records which removed using reduce. Suppose we had OCL 20 times then I need field count=20 in that records. If that possible, I will ask new question.

Comment: Oh, yes, absolutely. I'll add to my answer!

Comment: I mean to say, with every record I need that field(not separate count). Add new field `count` in JSON. Hope its clear. Then output JSON will have 3 field  `name` `value` and `count`

Comment: Ah, yes, no problem, I'll add the count field!

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know if this is the best way, but you should check the data before inserting new. Like check if the name : ABER is already in the file, else insert it

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get unique objects. It will resolve your problem.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    "name": "ABER",
    "value": 72
  },
  {
    "name": "HDCC",
    "value": 72
  },
  {
    "name": "HDCC",
    "value": 72
  },
  {
    "name": "OCL",
    "value": 42
  },
  {
    "name": "OCL",
    "value": 42
  }
]

getUniqueObj = (array) => {
  var flags = [],
    output = [],
    l = array.length,
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (flags[array[i].name]) continue;
    flags[array[i].name] = true;
    output.push({
      name: array[i].name,
      value: array[i].value
    });
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(getUniqueObj(arr1));
```

Comment: Hey! I am looking for kind of one line code w/o any loop